# Webpack unknown error : Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, terminal, webpack-4

I tried to learn simple project with MERN stack by doing example.
But i don't know why webpack didn't work and throw an error like this in terminal.

I'm using Ubuntu v16.04.

> npm run dev
>
> mern-stack@1.0.0 dev /home/trungh13/Dev/mern-stack
>
> webpack -wd
>   Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>   - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
>     object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }
>     -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! mern-stack@1.0.0 dev: `webpack -wd`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the mern-stack@1.0.0 dev script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Here is my package.json file:

```
  {
    "name": "mern-stack",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./server/server.js --ignore public/",
      "dev": "webpack -wd"
    },
    "author": "trungh13",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "ejs": "^2.5.7",
      "express": "^4.16.3",
      "mongodb": "^3.0.5",
      "react": "^16.2.0",
      "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
      "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
      "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
      "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
      "eslint": "^4.19.1",
      "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
      "nodemon": "^1.17.2",
      "webpack": "^4.2.0"

    }
  }
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports={
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public',
        filename:'bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test:/\.js$/,
                loader:'babel-loader'
            }
        ]    
    }
};
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is inside the `module` object. The `loaders` property is invalid and you should use the `rules` property instead. Also, in [webpack-4](/questions/tagged/webpack-4) you need to provide the `mode` property (possible values are `development`, `production` and `none`).

Another thing to mention is that you need to include the `webpack-cli` package in your `devDependencies` because in the latest version of webpack, the CLI tool was moved to this package: [webpack-cli](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)

Check this [webpack-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) project using **Webpack 4** configuration objects (for *development* and *production* environments).
I think the previous tutorial project could be helpful.

Comment: @trungh13 please, select the answer to indicates your question is solved